# Value not getting passed to body in post request Angular

Tags: angular

I am new to angular. In ts file the username and password is having the value.
In Service file the value is getting passed to the function but not to the body `var body = 'userName=username&password=password';`.

Kindly help on this.

**component.ts**:

```
loginSubmit(){         this.loginservice.login(this.f.username.value,this.f.password.value).subscribe(
                data =>
                {
                    this.objlogindata = data;
                    console.log(this.objlogindata);
                }
            )
          }
```

**service.ts**

```
login(username:any, password:any){
      var body = 'userName=this.username&password=this.password';
      const header = new HttpHeaders();
      const myheader = header.set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
      return this.http.post(this.loginUrl,body,{headers: myheader}).pipe(map((response: Response) => {
          let user = response.json();
          console.log(user);
      })
      );
  }
```

Comment: you don't pass the values to the string. use it like this: `var body = \`userName=${username}&password=${password}\``

Answer (score 0):

The `body` should be an json object

Try like this:

```
var body = { 
 userName=this.username,
 password=this.password'
};
```

Using **HttpClient**

```
 this.http.post(url, body).subscribe((resp: any) => {
      console.log(resp)
      let user = resp
 });
```

Comment: body as json object did not work.Anyways thanks for your response.

Comment: Have you tried calling the API via Postman? What is the body you send from there?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see which version of HttpClient You're using, but there are 2:

- old Http, You have to use `response.json()`
- new HttpClient, already uses `.json()` internally, just grab response.

also, `map()` is a data transformation operator, so you have to return result, 
like this

```
 let user = response.json();
return user;
```

Good luck!